# TDD on C# with Auto-Fixture how to populate big objects with schema validations

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, tdd, autofixture

i m making some tests on my project and using Fixture to populate big objects.
Those objects make part of an XML that has an schema.

```
//silly objects 
Fixture fixture = new Fixture();

boleto = fixture.Create<Boleto>();
agencia = fixture.Create<Agencia>();
pasajero = fixture.Create<Pasajero>();
aerolinea = fixture.Create<Aerolinea>();

//xml build
XmlMySuite objXmlMySuite = new XmlMySuite();

string strXML = objXmlMySuite.buildXML(aerolinea, pasajero, agencia);


//xml validation
XmlSchemaSet xmlSchema = new XmlSchemaSet();
xmlSchema .Add("schema.xsd");

bool errors = false;

Console.WriteLine("Attempting to validate");
XDocument custOrdDoc = XDocument.Load(new XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(strXML)));
custOrdDoc.Validate(xmlSchema , (o, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", e.Message);
    errors = true;
});
Console.WriteLine("custOrdDoc {0}", errors ? "did not validate" : "validated");
Console.WriteLine();

Assert.IsFalse(errors);
```

Is there any way to fill/populate the objects with Fixture validating that schema?

For example, one of the elements tag of the XML Schema is:

```
<xs:element name="Type">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:enumeration value="CCC"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="AAA"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="BBB"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="QQQQ"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Could you include the XML Schema Definition?

Comment: Sorry Mark it has a lot of private definitions i can t. I can put an element of the XML Schema

Comment: The most likely answer is *no*; at least, I don't see an easy way to do this. If you temporarily ignore AutoFixture, then how would you model your API with static typing in such a way that XSD compliance is guaranteed?

Comment: That said, if you can add Data Annotations on your classes, AutoFixture will respect some of these, like `[Range]`, `[StringLength]`, and `[RegularExpression]` (IIRC).

Comment: Mark... yes you are right using Data Annotations i can fix some of then. Tkanks a lot!